# Reading a text file line by line in C++

Tags: c++, string, io

How does the code below work ? where is the counter for the for-loop and how can i reset the counter to line number 0.

```
for (std::string line;std::getline(ifs, line); )
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for a counter. This is equivalent to

```
std::string line;
while(getline(ifs, line))
{
}
```

There are methods to move the input iterator back to the beginning of the file. Something like: `ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop is equivalent to:

```
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
    }
}
```

In other words: "keep iterating as long as `getline` returns `true`".

Comment: @rajat [Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2d6fx99(v=vs.110).aspx) through the file.

Comment: I found a easier way , i just close and reopen the file . > ifs.close();ifs.open(filename);

Comment: @rajat that may be 'easier', but it's a hack - reopening is slower than seeking. You **do** want to seek.

Comment: @rajat *::shudder::* Use `seek`. Just one system call instead of two, plus close/re-open introduces a race condition, and while errors related to that may be rare they will be effectively impossible to debug. For instance, on unix-like systems the file may have been deleted from the command line in the mean time and close and re-open will fail (because the file will be gone), while seeking will still work.

Answer (score 1):

And to reset the counter to line number 0 (i.e. to the beginning of stream) you should use

```
ifs.seekg (0, ios::beg);
```